launching default Gazebo stuck in ros2 humble
I try to run default installation of gazebo ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py terminal has following output
dell@ubuntu22:~$ ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/dell/.ros/log/2024-07-21-13-30-46-331042-ubuntu22-23786
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [23787]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [23789]


Gazebo is not running and the above terminal is there for all time
here is the gazebo.launch.py file
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.substitutions import ThisLaunchFileDir


def generate_launch_description():

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('gui', default_value='true',
                              description='Set to "false" to run headless.'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument('server', default_value='true',
                              description='Set to "false" not to run gzserver.'),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/gzserver.launch.py']),
            condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('server'))
        ),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/gzclient.launch.py']),
            condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
        ),
    ])



after few min like 10 to 15 following error message appeared on terminal
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Network is unreachable
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachableNetwork is unreachable
[gzclient-2] 
[gzclient-2] Exception sending a multicast message:Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable



Please edit to share what your log files say? How long did you wait?

@Tully thank you for response I update the message

From your error messages it seems that you have a networking issue. You'll need to explain your environment that you're running this in including network topology (include all interfaces) and any settings for your machine such as firewall rules etc.

I get the same exception when I execute the simulation for a long time. Did you find the cause of the message Exception sending a multicast message:Network is unreachable?
